# What does HTTParty::get return?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, httparty

I'm still new to Ruby and trying to use the HTTParty gem to help me write an API Wrapper. I feed HTTParty::get a URI and it parses JSON data. From a quick glance and the way the returned result behaves, it looks like a Hash, but is it? I can't seem to find information online. Another post on StackOverflow shows to use HTTParty::get(...).parsed_response to get the Hash, but this seems outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in the console:

```
>require 'httparty'
 => true
> response = HTTParty.get( "..." )
 ....
> response.class
 => HTTParty::Response
```

So the response from `HTTParty.get` is an `HTTParty::Response` object.

See [this blogpost titled "It's Time To HTTParty!"](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty) to learn more about how to work this response.

Comment: This is slightly off-topic. When writing an API wrapper, would it be preferred to return this Response object, or to convert it to a Hash? Or to create an instance of a Class with keys as fields/attributes?

Comment: Depends on the specific requirements I guess. I haven't worked much on API wrappers; probably best to ask a separate question.

Comment: @DillPixel By returning a non-standard object such as `HTTParty::Response` the API and its users are more insulated to change than using a simpler data type such as a hash. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/335847) for lots of good reasons. It's the same principle.